# Updating html div with xml content through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have banging my head against a cheese grater for awhile now on this. I have a component for my website to add a news ticker that is working with the divs hardcoded in the html

Working news ticker without xml: http://jsfiddle.net/17h0wa28/4/

I am looking to update this so that the content can be updated by a user without the need or fear of changing the html by having an xml file; the div's requires one to have a class of active to show on the ticker

```
<div class="newsTicker active">Latest News updates/ticker 1</div>
<div class="newsTicker">Latest News updates/ticker 2</div>
etc....
```

I have tried several different methods and attacks but non seem to be working correctly giving errors all over the place and/or no output on the html page

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NEWSFEED>

    <STATUS>
        <UPDATE>Latest News updates/ticker 1</UPDATE>
    </STATUS>

    <STATUS>
        <UPDATE>Latest News updates/ticker 2</UPDATE>
    </STATUS>

    <STATUS>
        <UPDATE>Latest News updates/ticker 3</UPDATE>
    </STATUS>

    <STATUS>
        <UPDATE>Latest News updates/ticker 4</UPDATE>
    </STATUS>

</NEWSFEED>
```

Code for html/xml update(newsFeed.xml)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            myFunction(xmlhttp);
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "newsFeed.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    };

    function myFunction(xmlhttp, test) {

        var x, i, xmlDoc, feed;

        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        feed = "";
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("UPDATE");

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            feed += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }

        document.getElementByClassName("newsContent").innerHTML = '<div class="newsTicker">' + feed + '</div>';
    }

});
```

Update:

It appears that my main issue is the retrieval of the xml file itself; in testing this script is producing error. Depending on location of the xmlhttp.open, I get an ready state of either 0 or 1, never 4 or the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Where am I going wrong? I have also tried ajax and get the same issue

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            alert(success);
        } else {
            alert(failed to get file);
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "newsFeed.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you are getting your xml document back this might work:

```
function myFunction(xmlhttp, test) {

    var x, i, xmlDoc, feed;

    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    feed = "";
    i = 0;
    $('STATUS',xml).each(function() {
       feed = $(this).find('UPDATE').text(); 
       if (i == 0){
          html = html + '<div class="newsTicker active">' + feed + '</div>'
       } else  {
          html = html + '<div class="newsTicker">' + feed + '</div>'
       }
       i++
    }); 
$('.newsContent').html(html);
}
```

Comment: so as it turns out, you led me into propbably the root cause, where, I am not getting connected to the xml file

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert('succes');
        } else {
            alert('failure);
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "newsFeed.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    };

appears that i am getting either ready state 0 or 1 depending on location of the xmlhttp.open line

where am i going wrong?????

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out my main issue with the document being read.  Apparently ie and chrome do not like the code "new XMLHttpRequest();" being ran on the local pc for testing.  Running the same code in firefox produced the response and status correclty.

Thankyou Jeremy in more ways then one.  After switching browsers to verify and test I was able to get the call and read done correctly.....Your a life saver!